# AngularJS "Wire up a Backend" example is still not working well

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to run (locally) the third example in AngularJS http://angularjs.org/new called "Wire up a Backend" with no luck (on Chrome).

It complains about:

```
           Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]   
           http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=project&p1=Error%3A…
           oogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A29%3A56) angular.js:3577
```

Here is the HTML/JS files:

**index.html:**

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html ng-app="project">
              <head>
                <script                 
                src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-
                route.js"></script>
                <script 
                src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js">
                </script>   

                <script                 
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-
            resource.min.js">
                </script>   
                <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
                <script 
            src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.min.js">                                
            </script>
                <script src="project.js"></script>
              </head>
              <body>
                <h2>JavaScript Projects</h2>
                <div ng-view></div>
              </body>
            </html>
```

**project.js**

```
            angular.module('project', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])

            .value('fbURL', 'https://angularjs-projects.firebaseio.com/')

            .factory('Projects', function($firebase, fbURL) {
              return $firebase(new Firebase(fbURL));
            })

            .config(function($routeProvider) {
              $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                  controller:'ListCtrl',
                  templateUrl:'list.html'
                })
                .when('/edit/:projectId', {
                  controller:'EditCtrl',
                  templateUrl:'detail.html'
                })
                .when('/new', {
                  controller:'CreateCtrl',
                  templateUrl:'detail.html'
                })
                .otherwise({
                  redirectTo:'/'
                });
            })

            .controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, Projects) {
              $scope.projects = Projects;
            })

            .controller('CreateCtrl', function($scope, $location, $timeout, Projects) {
              $scope.save = function() {
                Projects.$add($scope.project, function() {
                  $timeout(function() { $location.path('/'); });
                });
              };
            })

            .controller('EditCtrl',
              function($scope, $location, $routeParams, $firebase, fbURL) {
                var projectUrl = fbURL + $routeParams.projectId;
                $scope.project = $firebase(new Firebase(projectUrl));

                $scope.destroy = function() {
                  $scope.project.$remove();
                  $location.path('/');
                };

                $scope.save = function() {
                  $scope.project.$save();
                  $location.path('/');
                };
            });
```

**list.html**

```
            <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="search-query"                 
                placeholder="Search">

            <table>
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Project</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th><a href="#/new"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a></th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="project in projects | orderByPriority | filter:search |                 
            orderBy:'name'">
                <td><a href="{{project.site}}" target="_blank">{{project.name}}</a>                
            </td>
                <td>{{project.description}}</td>
                <td>
                  <a href="#/edit/{{project.$id}}"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

**details.html**

```
            <form name="myForm">
              <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: myForm.name.$invalid}">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="project.name" required>
                <span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required" class="help-inline">
                    Required</span>
              </div>

              <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: myForm.site.$invalid}">
                <label>Website</label>
                <input type="url" name="site" ng-model="project.site" required>
                <span ng-show="myForm.site.$error.required" class="help-inline">
                    Required</span>
                <span ng-show="myForm.site.$error.url" class="help-inline">
                    Not a URL</span>
              </div>

              <label>Description</label>
              <textarea name="description" ng-model="project.description"></textarea>

              <br>
              <a href="#/" class="btn">Cancel</a>
              <button ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"
                      class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
              <button ng-click="destroy()"
                      ng-show="project.$remove" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </form>
```

Am I missing something?

By the way, I read other posts on relating to this issue, for instance: [AngularFire beginner doesn't work example "Wire up a Backend" from angularjs.org (solved-no css ref., chrome issue duplicated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253856/angularfire-beginner-doesnt-work-example-wire-up-a-backend-from-angularjs-org) but this was with older angularJS version and different error which apparently was missing bootstrap css

Comment: How are we supposed to help without seeing any of your code?

Comment: I downloaded the four files the example requires (index.html, list.html. details.html and project.js, I opened index.html with Chrome and saw this error in Chrome debugger/console. The files are taken from the example "Wire up a Backend" in http://angularjs.org/new

Comment: please, provide template of Plunker or Fiddle with your attempts and try to reproduce the issue there

Comment: @MaximShoustin apparently JSFiddle is limited to one HTML page while I have three in the example (index, list & details)

Comment: right, so use Plunker

Comment: I added the html/js files see above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I follow the link in the exception I get this message:

> In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.x, be sure that you've installed ngRoute.

I just had to add the `angular-route.min.js` to the `head` of `index.html` and everything seems to work as expected:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if it helped!

**Edit**

This is my `head` of `index.html`

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="project.js"></script>
</head>
```

Apart from this, I didn't modify anything else, all sources are downloaded directly from your link.

Comment: Hi, I followed your instruction and got this error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'module' of undefined angular-route.js:25 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=project&p1=Error%3A…oogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A29%3A56)

Comment: have you included `ngRoute` in your module's dependencies?

Comment: Yep, like this:

angular.module('project', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])

And it gave me this error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Please see my update, in your code angular.js is not the first script you load.

Comment: Hi @Uri I got everything actually running but for the edit dialog. The data won't load from the Firebase into the fields when on edit mode, so nothing really happens there. Did you get it to run *stock* or did you have to do further changes?

Comment: I just checked and edit part works without any further changes, but it takes a second or two before the data is displayed.

Comment: @MonkeyCoder Yes, it's working now. It turned out I missed out a trailing slash at the end of the Firebase URL, which broke that particular part of the app. I got help through this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928110/angularjs-wire-up-a-backend-example-not-loading-data-on-edit-dialog . Cheers!