# AngularJS “Wire up a Backend” example not loading data on edit dialog

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm new to Firebase... I'm trying to get the **"Wire up a Backend"** example at [Angularjs](http://angularjs.org/)' home page to run locally.

I got past the common `ngRoute` problem and **the app is actually working fine**, *except for the edit dialog, that doesn't load data from the Firebase*.

The `list.html` partial loads fine and renders the data, and the `detail.html` also loads fine when loaded by the `CreateCtrl` controller, which does save data to the `Firebase` as expected.

The problem is with the `EditCtrl` controller, which renders the `detail.html` partial **without** the record's data in the fields.

What makes me nuts is that the example at Angular's page seems to use the exact same code, and everything works at their end. I've tried isolating the problem, with no avail.

I've converted the example into an app and created [a repository at Github](https://github.com/dreamyguy/color-consolidator). The repo is bloated with unrelated development stuff, but the app is supposed to work straight out of the [ZIP](https://github.com/dreamyguy/color-consolidator/archive/master.zip) file.

Really appreciate any leads, cheers!

**app.js**

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('project', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])

.value('fbURL', 'https://color-consolidator.firebaseio.com')

.factory('Projects', function($firebase, fbURL) {
    return $firebase(new Firebase(fbURL));
});

myAppModule.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller:'ListCtrl',
        templateUrl:'list.html'
    })
    .when('/edit/:projectId', {
        controller:'EditCtrl',
        templateUrl:'detail.html'
    })
    .when('/new', {
        controller:'CreateCtrl',
        templateUrl:'detail.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/'
    });
});

myAppModule.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, Projects) {
    firebaseConn();
    $scope.projects = Projects;
});

myAppModule.controller('CreateCtrl', function($scope, $location, $timeout, Projects) {
    firebaseConn();
    $scope.save = function() {
        Projects.$add($scope.project, function() {
            $timeout(function() { $location.path('/'); });
        });
    };
});

myAppModule.controller('EditCtrl', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, $firebase, fbURL) {
    firebaseConn();
    var projectUrl = fbURL + $routeParams.projectId;
    $scope.project = $firebase(new Firebase(projectUrl));
    $scope.destroy = function() {
        $scope.project.$remove();
        $location.path('/');
    };
    $scope.save = function() {
        $scope.project.$save();
        $location.path('/');
    };
});
```

**detail.html**

```
<form class="form-group" name="myForm">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{error: myForm.name.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="project.name" required>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required">Required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{error: myForm.site.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label" for="site">Site URL</label>
        <input type="url" class="form-control" name="site" ng-model="project.site" required>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.site.$error.required">Required</span>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.site.$error.url">Not a URL</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="description" ng-model="project.description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <a href="#/" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="destroy()" ng-show="project.$remove">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If you go here: https://angularjs-projects.firebaseio.com/# you get the raw view of data. It is not editable. I would think that for the sake of the project, the repository itself is read-only.

Comment: Hi Eugene, I have seen that. This Firebase is not directly editable, but anyone can add data to it by testing the example at Angular's page. It does reset itself after a while, though. I created my own Firebase on my app, so that I can test freely. It's here: https://color-consolidator.firebaseio.com and it was initialized by importing the `json` as it is on https://angularjs-projects.firebaseio.com/. If you have the time, please download the ZIP file at Github I mentioned on my description and see the what I mean... Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your urls:

from this:

```
https://color-consolidator.firebaseio.com
```

to this:

```
https://color-consolidator.firebaseio.com/
```

I've created a pull request on your repo with the fix implemented.

Comment: The culprit is this line: `var projectUrl = fbURL + $routeParams.projectId;`, without the trailing `/` character, the string concatenation would result in an invalid URL.